# Where is the "Known As" field in Exchange 2007 / AD?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, active-directory, ldap

Does anyone know how to update the "Known As" field for a contact in Outlook?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWFhK.jpg)

I have looked through all the properties of the contact in both Active Directory and Exchange Management Console, but I can't find any corresponding field.

There's a service running somewhere in our domain that updates this field from a different database, so I know that it *is* possible to update it somehow, but I can't seem to find a way to do so manually.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this is a contact's Nickname field. There is no LDAP/AD mapping for this field unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks - but surely there has to be a way to edit it - if not from LDAP/AD then somewhere else?

Comment: Where did you take this screenshot?

Comment: This is from Outook - when you right-click on a name and click on "Outlook Properties". This field is read-only though.